# accessing inbox, given a particular date

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, sms, cursor

Hello guys i want to accesss certain sms according to the specified month, like for example, current month and last month.  etc.

i have written this query, which is not working , little help needed..?

```
Cursor c1;
    String[] projection={"_id","address", "date"};

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    String where= month +"=date(date,%m)";
    c1 = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), projection,where, null,null);
```

Also can anyone tell me why i am gettig an error on the commented code line below

```
c2 = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                null, android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE+"="+android.provider.CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE, null,null);


        if(c2!=null){
            callArray[2]= "RECEIVED "+c2.getCount();    
            callArray[3]= "INCOMING Duration : "+00.00;
            //c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION));
        }else{
            callArray[2]= "RECEIVED "+0;
            callArray[3]= "INCOMING Duration :"+0;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
String where = String.format("'%02d'", month) + " = strftime('%m', date)";
```

Comment: i tried that and i am getting sql lite run time exception, saying some syntax error in %

Comment: 03-20 11:23:57.156: E/AndroidRuntime(1446): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tech.madmax.android.grid/com.tech.madmax.android.grid.SmsActivity_adv}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, address, date FROM sms WHERE (type=1) AND (strftime(%m, date) = 3) ORDER BY date DESC

Comment: You forgot the quotes around the `%m`.

Comment: the code is compiling but not showing any difference, i wonder whats the problem

Comment: `strftime` returns a zero-padded string, not a number. Updated.

Comment: what exactly is the output of strftime, what do u mean by padding

Comment: `strftime('%m', '2001-02-03')` returns `'02'`.